# Proof of 1/n (where n is from Natural Numbers) as neither open nor closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have a doubt with the proof of 1/n being neither open nor closed. I have seen various replies to similar queries; however, none of them seems to be speaking of the same reasons. So, I would like to know a conclusive proof of the assertion.

Thanks
Jai

Comment: I can't imagine that the proofs differ in any significant way.  Can you describe one of the arguments you are familiar with and explain why you think it is incomplete?

Comment: $1/n$ is a number, not a set. As written, this makes no sense.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo : OP means $\{\frac1n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$

Answer (score 7):

A set is open if all its points are interior points. But no point of $\{1/n\}$ is interior, so it's not an open set.

A set is closed if it contains all its limit points. But $0$ is a limit point of $\{1/n\}$ which is not in the set, so it's not a closed set.

Comment: do you mean to say "if and only if" in the first sentence? as written, seems like maybe it could be open if other conditions were met.

Answer (score 7):

To simplify notation, write $X = \{ \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

- To see that $X$ isn't open, note that $1 \in X$, but $1+\varepsilon \not \in X$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$.
- To see that $X$ isn't closed, you can prove that its complement isn't open. To see this, note that $0 \not \in X$, but $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \cap X \ne \varnothing$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$.

There are still some details to be worked out (by you).

Comment: Nicely succinct, easily understood. +1 for you.